# Configuring Gmail Hosts and Content Compliance rules using SDK or API (Powershell alternative for gmail)

Tags: sdk, gmail, gmail-api, google-workspace

I constantly have to configure hosts, API permissions, and create Content Compliance Rules in various Google Workspace environments. I do something similar with Office 365 so I wrote a Powershell script to do everything for me. I am trying to find out of there's an SDK or API I could use with Gmail to do something similar. All of the documentation I see for Google API suggests there is no API endpoint to accomplish this. I do see there's an SDK but I'm not seeing anything in there either that appears to address my needs.

Wondering if anyone could share some insights or confirm that it is not possible. Google documentation is mediocre at best and the community here is more likely to know, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

As you might suggest over the question. You are correct. By itself the Gmail API documentation is not fully clear and also it is not possible to build compliance rules in various Gmail environments.

The Gmail API is little limited to those types of functions. I do think it is an excellent idea or feature that should be implemented to modify or create compliance rules in the future. I would suggest sharing the feedback or requesting a feature over their official page:

- https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/support

Comment: I appreciate the response and clarification. I will add that suggestion on their site. Thank you for your response.